# Conditionally pass optional parameters in C#

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, long-parameter-list

I have a function with more than 10 optional parameters, and I have settings in my program to determine if a parameter should be passed or not. For example,

```
public void MyFunction(bool? b1=null, bool? b2=null, bool? b3=null.. bool? b10=null)
```

The following are the settings that dictate if parameters should be set or not

```
bool setb1 = false;
bool setb2 = false;
bool setb3 = true;
bool setb4 = false;
bool setb5 = true;
```

If I were to follow the settings to set parameters, then I will have to do something like this

```
if (!setb1 && !setb2 && !setb4)
   MyFunction(b3: value3, b5: value5);
```

If I have 10 settings and 10 parameters, then I will have too many combinations, so I don't think my implementation is feasible. What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: More than 10 optional parameters? You are perhaps better off bundling the method arguments as properties/fields in a struct/class. So the user can set whaterver properties he wants/needs to...

Comment: Remove all those ugly optional parameters and use a class instead, which will contain those parameters as properties.

Comment: Use dictionary or even a simple array instead of this (ugly) techinque.

Comment: If you can't change your method signature, the only way to do this is via reflection. If you can change the method signature, please use a different data model as others have suggested.

Comment: Seems like you should try to use the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I am not the author of the code, so I will need to get more clarification to get this changed.

Comment: If your coworker actually wrote a method that takes 60 parameters, I'm not sure you're going to be able to reason with him. That's insane.

Answer (score 4):

Your function has a [Long Parameter List](http://principles-wiki.net/anti-patterns:long_parameter_list)

I would pass an object be the parameter, creating a class `ConditionModle`

You can encapsulate conditions you want in this class.

```
public class ConditionModle
{
    public bool setb1 { get; set; }
    public bool setb2 { get; set; }
    public bool setb3 { get; set; }
    public bool setb4 { get; set; }
    public bool setb5 { get; set; }
    ....
    public bool Condition1()
    {
        return !this.setb1 && !this.setb2 && !this.setb4;
    }
}

if (model.Condition1())
    MyFunction(model);
```

This solution could help your code

1. Clearer,
2. Add new property or judgment methods will not affect the previous method.
3. Add new property you will not modify call method parameter.

Comment: Assuming all your data types are the same (`bool?`) you could also use a `Dictionary<string, bool>`. You just need to check if the key is present then check its value.

Comment: I am not too clear how your method will be easier. WIth your method, I would need to have many "Conditional()" functions, wouldn't I?

Comment: In my opinion, the method of responsibility is as simple as possible. The name of the method is an action meaning. Although there are many methods, each method has its meaning. It is easier to understand than looking at `!setb1 && !setb2 && !setb4` :)

Comment: I see. This function I am working on actually has well over 60 parameters... I used 10 to simplify the problem a bit. So I will have too many conditional functions if I were to build a function for each combination.